# How to open an entire folder through CMD to VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmd

I want to open my entire folder through CMD but I can't seem to find a efficient solution for it.
Let's say my folder's name is `source`:

```
$ cd source
$ code index.html
$ code style.css
$ code script.js
```

I don't want to open each one of the files as I did in the above, because I have many files in this folder.

Thanks

Comment: Did you read the Visual Studio Code documentation page [The Visual Studio Code command-line options](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line)? It does not look so. Please always read first the documentation of a used application, command, library, function, structure, etc. before asking others for help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From inside the project directory you can use `code .`